# dynamic data masking read uncommited

Tags: sql-server, isolation-level, dynamic-data-masking

I have read about Dynamic Data Masking and one question is still in my mind. I am wondering what will happen is such scenario:
1. Dynamic Data Masking is set up on table
2. ETL process is loading new rows using NOLOCK hint (read uncommited) 
3. During data load, execute select statement with read uncommited isolation level to get "dirty read" rows.

Does this "dirty data" will masked or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic Data Masking doesn't affect stored pages and it will work the same way with any transaction isolation level.

from Microsoft documentation(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Dynamic data masking is easy to use with existing applications, since
>   masking rules are applied in the query results.